# Cannot install ggplot2: "Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found"

Tags: r, ubuntu, ggplot2

Last week I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10.  The first time I've tried to use ggplot in RStudio since the update, I'm getting dependancy errors with my ggplot package and its no longer registered as installed (was working fine before).  When I try to reinstal ggplot2:

```
install.packages("ggplot2",dep=TRUE)
```

The installation fails while trying to install the dependencies.  Here's what the tail of the output looks like:

```
* installing *source* package ‘stringr’ ...
** package ‘stringr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/home/james/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/stringr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package ‘reshape2’
* removing ‘/home/james/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/reshape2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reshape2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘reshape2’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/james/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpWNyAha/downloaded_packages’
```

I have a feeling this is the line (below) I should be looking at, but I'm not sure how to interprete this error, anyone have any suggestions for me?  I really have no idea where to go from here, as I couldent find any other people experiencing the same error as me.

```
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
```

Not sure if the Ubuntu upgrade I did relates to this... but I thought'd I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: You should use quotes: `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: Good catch!  But this was actually just a type-o in my question, as I did include the quotes to get the output I posted.  I've updated the post.

Comment: Try reinstalling the package `stringi` with `install.packages("stringi")`

Comment: It seems that `dependencies = TRUE` is failing with `ggplot2`. So, you need to `install.packages("stringr", dep=TRUE)`, then `install.packages("ggplot2", dep=TRUE)`.

Comment: @Pascal: That was my first thought, but the dependency flag is actually working fine.  The error comes about during the installation of the dependant package `stringr`.  Even when running `install.packages("stringi")`, the error still comes up.  @Nick Kennedy:  Awesome!  That was it! I didn't realize that `stringi` was a package.  There was an error in the installation of that dependant package.  I've added an answer below to show the final steps I had to take to resolve it.

Comment: Type-o, meant to write: Even when running `install.packages("stringr")`, the error still comes up

Comment: Interestingly, I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Installing "stringi" allowed me to install the ggplot2. I downloaded it and installed from Ubuntu command line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Following @Nick Kennedey's comment, I tried installing `stringi` like this:

```
> install.packages("stringi",dep=TRUE)
```

Which resulted in this error I hadn't seen before:

```
2015-08-07 10:26:35 (256 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpQI4Uau/downloaded_packages/stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz’ saved [3639183/3639183]

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/james/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/james/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/00LOCK-stringi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpQI4Uau/downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("stringi",dep=TRUE)
```

So the I followed the suggestion in the error an removed the LOCK folder.

In the terminal: `rm -r /home/james/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/00LOCK-stringi’`

Then tried installing the `stringi` package again, and it worked!  This was the issue... now I've just finished installing with no issues.

I am still a little bit confused though... as to how this error can come about.  Any ideas on what causes this so I can avoid it in the future?  Is it possible it was a symptom of my recent upgrade to 14.10?

Comment: `install.packages("stringr", dep=TRUE)` installs `stringi`...  But `install.packages("ggplot2", dep=TRUE)` doesn't install neither `stringi` nor `stringr`.

Comment: in this case not... i looked through my RStudio history, and I can confirm that I already tried `install.packages("stringr" = TRUE)` last night and that did not resolve the error.  I dont have the original console output anymore, but I thought I remembered the `stringr` install returning the exact same error I was getting when installing `ggplot2` with dependencies.  Only when I tried installing `stringi` did I see this new error which pointed to the solution

Comment: In my case, this was caused by me canceling the installation progress by force closing R. This resulted in the creation but not deletion of some temporary folder: `ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/00LOCK-stringi’`. I deleted the folder as directed, reinstalled `stringi` and it works.

Comment: Do you have a `.RProfile` in you home directory or in you `R` folder , if you do then please can you write the content of it ?

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error while installing `install.packages("knitr")`

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/stringi/libs/stringi.so'

I solved it by doing the below:

**In Ubuntu 16.04 and above**

`sudo apt install r-cran-stringi`

**In earlier versions (which had apt-get)**

`sudo apt-get install r-cran-stringi`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved the problem through installing stringi and ggplot2 from the terminal of linux. The problem has some relation with RStudio.