# shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found

Tags: rstudio

Just a few days ago I had no issues loading packages, now I get  "shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found" whenever I try to load a few packages. I tried installing stringi but I still kept getting the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please add more details and relevant code, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It self resolved. The package needed update

Comment: Did you see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866299/cannot-install-ggplot2-error-in-library-dynamlib-package-package-lib-sha)?