# Do I need to install.packages every time I use Rscript in linux command line?

Tags: r, command-line, rscript

I am using bio3d package in R and use Rscript to run it in the Linux command line. Do I need to install packages every time I run the R file or only library it after the first time of installation like what we used to do in the Rstudio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install a package once per installation of R/major R version.  (A "major version" of R refers to the second digit of the version number, e.g. you need to re-install packages when moving from version 3.5.2 to 3.6.0 or from 3.6.1 to 4.0.1, but not when moving from version 4.0.0 to 4.0.1.)

Comment: Thank you. But I received this error when I only library(bio3d) after installation:Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bio3d’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘bio3d.so’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘as.pdb.default’, ‘as.pdb.mol2’, ‘as.pdb.prmtop’, ‘atom2ele.default’, ‘atom2ele.pdb’, ‘atom2mass.default’, ‘atom2mass.pdb’, ‘atom.select.pdb’, ‘atom.select.mol2’, ‘atom.select.prmtop’, ‘bhattacharyya.array’, ‘bhattacharyya.enma’, ‘bhattacharyya.matrix’, ‘bhattacharyya.nma’, ‘bhattacharyya.pca’...

Comment: this is not typical; something else is wrong.  Do any of these answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866299/cannot-install-ggplot2-error-in-library-dynamlib-package-package-lib-sha